# Can you use dplyr across() to iterate across pairs of columns?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, across

I have 18 pairs of variable and I would like to do pair-wise math on them to calculate 18 new variables. The across() function in dplyr is quite handy when applying a formula to one column. Is there a way to apply across() to pairs of columns?

Tiny example with simple division of 2 variables (my actual code will be more complex, some ifelse, ...):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)

# filler data
df <- data.frame("label" = c('a','b','c','d'),
                 "A" = c(4, 3, 8, 9),
                 "B" = c(10, 0, 4, 1),
                 "error_A" = c(0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1),
                 "error_B" = c(0.3, 0, 0.4, 0.1))

# what I want to have in the end 
# instead of just 2 (A, B), I have 18
df1 <- df %>% mutate(
  'R_A' = A/error_A,
  'R_B' = B/error_B
)

# what I'm thinking about doing to use both variables A and error_A to calculate the new column
df2 <- df %>% mutate(
  across(c('A','B'),
         ~.x/{HOW DO I USE THE COLUMN WHOSE NAME IS glue('error_',.x)}
         .names = 'R_{.col}'
)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option is `map/reduce`.  Specify the columns of interest ('nm1'), loop over them in `map`, `select` those columns from the dataset, `reduce` by dividing, `rename` the columns after column binding (`_dfc`), and bind those with the original dataset

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
nm1 <- c('A', 'B')
map_dfc(nm1, ~ df %>% 
                select(ends_with(.x)) %>% 
                reduce(., `/`) ) %>%
    rename_all(~ str_c('R_', nm1)) %>%
    bind_cols(df, .)
```

-output

```
#  label A  B error_A error_B R_A      R_B
#1     a 4 10     0.4     0.3  10 33.33333
#2     b 3  0     0.3     0.0  10      NaN
#3     c 8  4     0.2     0.4  40 10.00000
#4     d 9  1     0.1     0.1  90 10.00000
```

---

Or another option with `across`

```
df %>% 
    mutate(across(c(A, B), ~ 
     ./get(str_c('error_', cur_column() )), .names = 'R_{.col}' ))
#  label A  B error_A error_B R_A      R_B
#1     a 4 10     0.4     0.3  10 33.33333
#2     b 3  0     0.3     0.0  10      NaN
#3     c 8  4     0.2     0.4  40 10.00000
#4     d 9  1     0.1     0.1  90 10.00000
```

Answer (score 6):

One option could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(across(c(A, B), .names = "R_{col}")/across(starts_with("error")))

  label A  B error_A error_B R_A      R_B
1     a 4 10     0.4     0.3  10 33.33333
2     b 3  0     0.3     0.0  10      NaN
3     c 8  4     0.2     0.4  40 10.00000
4     d 9  1     0.1     0.1  90 10.00000
```

Comment: This is really weird, but cool. I wondered why this is even working, but it looks like you create two `tibbles` with `across()` and then divide them. Kudos.

Answer (score 3):

I like akruns answer above, especially the approach with `cur_column()`. Interestingly, `cur_column()` can't be used with {rlang}'s evaluation (`!! sym(paste0("error_", cur_column()))`), but `get` is a nice workaround.

Just to add one more approach, which also works under dpylr < 1.0.0. I usually use a `mutate` custom function together with `purrr::reduce()`. In this function `x` is your string stem and you construct all variables you want to access with `!! sym(paste0(...))`. On the left hand-side you can just use {rlang}'s glue syntax.

You apply this custom function by calling `reduce()` on the vector of strings and your `data.frame` goes in the `.init =  .` argument.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)


# filler data
df <- data.frame("label" = c('a','b','c','d'),
                 "A" = c(4, 3, 8, 9),
                 "B" = c(10, 0, 4, 1),
                 "error_A" = c(0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1),
                 "error_B" = c(0.3, 0, 0.4, 0.1))

gen_vars1 <- function(df, x) {
  
  mutate(df,
         "R_{x}" := !! sym(x) / !! sym(paste0("error_", x)))
}

df %>% 
  reduce(c("A", "B"), gen_vars1, .init = .)
#>   label A  B error_A error_B R_A      R_B
#> 1     a 4 10     0.4     0.3  10 33.33333
#> 2     b 3  0     0.3     0.0  10      NaN
#> 3     c 8  4     0.2     0.4  40 10.00000
#> 4     d 9  1     0.1     0.1  90 10.00000
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I once opened a [feature request](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/4834) for this kind of problem, but apparently it is too special case for {dplyr}. When you follow the link you can also find another option to do this kind of operation.

Comment: I see this feature being useful for longitudinal data where the same transformation is desired at each wave. The user must either write syntactically complex functions as shown above, or pivot the data long by wave, make transformations once, and then pivot back to wide.

Answer (score 2):

For such cases I find base R solution straight-forward and efficient too. It doesn't require to loop over columns or unique values. You define two groups of column and divide them directly.

For the example that you have shared we can identify `"A"` and `"B"` columns by looking for columns names that have only one character in them.

```
cols <- grep('^.$', names(df), value = TRUE)
error_cols <- grep('error', names(df), value = TRUE)

df[paste0('R_', cols)] <- df[cols]/df[error_cols]
df

#  label A  B error_A error_B R_A  R_B
#1     a 4 10     0.4     0.3  10 33.3
#2     b 3  0     0.3     0.0  10  NaN
#3     c 8  4     0.2     0.4  40 10.0
#4     d 9  1     0.1     0.1  90 10.0
```